# Locomotive doesn't work on a debian system: sl ls

Tags: debian, command-line, package-management, ls

**PROBLEM:**

I installed `sl` but when I type `sl` on the command line I get this:

```
bash: sl: command not found
```

---

```
(root@host)-(03:55:38)-(/home/user)
$apt install sl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sl is already the newest version (3.03-17+b2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

> Sl is a program that can display animations aimed to correct you if
>   you type 'sl' by mistake. SL stands for Steam Locomotive.  [package on
>   Debian packages](https://packages.debian.org/stable/sl)

---

[Installation instructions on cyberciti.biz/](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/displays-animations-when-accidentally-you-type-sl-instead-of-ls.html)

Excerpt:

Install sl software to get Steam Locomotive ( train in shell )

Type the following apt-get command/apt command on a `Debian` / Ubuntu Linux:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sl
```

**Usage**

Okay, just mistyped ls command as sl:

```
$ sl
```

---

```
(root@host)-(03:57:47)-(/home/user)
$cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

---

```
(root@host)-(04:04:01)-(/home/user)
$bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

**QUESTION:**

What is happening here, where is the locomotive, is there something I need to configure.......?

Comment: Is `/usr/games` in your path? What is `type sl`? Does `hash -r` make a difference? Does `LS` work?

Comment: @MichaelHomer that did the trick, thank's, are you writing an answer or should I

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running as `root` (I'm guessing you might be since you ran `apt` directly), `PATH` by default will exclude `/usr/local/games` and `/usr/games` due to a conditional in `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

`sl` happens to be in `/usr/games`.

Comment: just so you know this is not a problem if I was using fedora because it has some config there were it runs without games